# Do big outdoor planters need a saucer?

Tags: plant-health, containers, outdoor

I wanted to build a two-foot (24”) square planter from left-over tiles. I will drill small holes at the bottom, so it will have drainage holes. These planters will be moved to an outdoor area where there’s lots of sun.

My question: when a planter is this big, will the plant actually benefit from the excess water (if any) that the saucer picks up?

Comment: I use saucers only to stop water from draining out of the pot onto the wood deck. I have already replaced rotten wood that was under pots with no saucers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much water is available, whether a saucer is needed for your container. For example, for my large containers in the garden I place saucers under them during the summer. The reason is that during summer the weather can be hot and dry, and any water I or the sky gives to the plants is saved by these saucers. If your climate is wet and not dry though, it won't be necessary to use saucers. During winter, which are often cold and wet here in Europe, I remove the saucers and place the containers on wooden deck tiles or pallets.